# Having trouble compiling Three20 sample TTCatalog

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, three20

I downloaded from git a copy of the latest three20, and I keep running into errors when I try to compile the sample code in the folder.

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification", referenced from:
      _UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification$non_lazy_ptr in libThree20UINavigator.a(TTBaseNavigator.o)
     (maybe you meant: _UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification$non_lazy_ptr)
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm running Xcode 3.2.3, compiling to Debug simulator 4.0

Any ideas on what to do?

I've compiled once before a while ago, before I forgot about it.  Can't seem to recompile anymore.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the usual suspects of Clean All Targets and XCode/Empty Caches, and/or restart XCode.

Comment: hmm, I tried all of those, to no avail.  Do you know if anything changed in three20 since now and July 2010?

Comment: I downloaded a different copy, and I get this different error now:

Comment: ld: duplicate symbol _TTCreateNonRetainingArray in /Users/jonguan/facebook-ios-sdk/three20/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libThree20Core.a(TTGlobalCore.o) and /Users/jonguan/facebook-ios-sdk/three20/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libThree20.a(TTGlobalCore.o)

Comment: OK!  Solved the problem by downloading ANOTHER copy of three20.